# When posting on super user keep getting "An error occured submiting the question"

Tags: support, questions

I'm trying to post a question on superuser.com but keep getting the message "An error occurred submitting the question" when I click Post Your Question. 
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

SuperUser was recently switched over to the CloudFlare content distribution network, and they are having some problems with the integration in the early-going. If you have this problem, keep trying, or try again later. Most of us regulars on the site have seen this sporadically over the past week or so.